# How to get monitor native resolution without disconnecting HDMI cable?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have DELL U3417W monitor with 512MB ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670 (Dell) graphics card on Dell™ Studio XPS™ 1640 on windows 10 Home edition.

My laptop sometime loose monitor native resolution of 3440 x 1440 and revert back to 1920x1080. I have to disconnect HDMI cable wait for 5 seconds and connect back. This is a problem in long term as it might just cause tear and wear in HDMI port on laptop. Is there any way to simulate physical disconnect and reconnect of HDMI cable through powershell script or some other way?

Comment: Web serches show that the ATI Mobility Radeon 3670 max digital [resolution](http://www.mobilegpu.com/prodetail1493474.html) for external monitors is of 2560 x 1600. This could be the cause of the switch to a lower resolution. You should try to set the monitor to the supported resolution and possibly to connect the monitor to the DisplayPort available on your laptop

Comment: @spike_66, Thanks for taking time to look into this. Actually, I have no problem getting 3440x1440. The max resolution supported is 3840x2160. See the link

https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/mobility-radeon-hd-3670.c1622

The issue is after few days or weeks, the graphics card seem to be choking and crashing reverting resolution to 1920x1080. In order to get the 3440x1440, I have to disconnect HDMI cable and reconnect after 1 min. Now, how I can do this programmatically? I don't want to restart machine either.

Comment: Glad that it works for you, but the ATI Mobility Radeon 3670 chip was released in 2008. Frankly, I don't think it was designed to support 34-inch monitors.

Comment: I was blown away by that too. I bought this Dell XPS 1640 laptop in 2008. By 2017, it got very slow. I opened it clean up dust. Re-Apply thermal paste. Upgraded RAM. Removed CD DROM and added an extra SSD drive. Upgraded to Windows 10. I have emotional attachment to this machine so will keep using as long as I can.

Comment: Well, the addition of the SSD drive along with more RAM will surely have added some speed to the good old laptop. Take care of it. Good luck